# Definition of Sobolev space using differential operators

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry

I've sometimes seen it written that the Sobolev space $H^d=W^{d,2}$ on a closed Riemannian manifold $M$ can be defined using any first-order *elliptic operator* $D$ as follows. For any $f\in C_c^\infty(M)$, define
$$\|f\|_{H^d}=\sum_{i=0}^d\|D^i f\|_{L^2(M)}.$$
Then $H^d(M)$ is defined as the completion of $C_c^\infty(M)$ under this norm.

**Question 1:** How do we show that for two such elliptic operators $D_1$ and $D_2$ that the resulting norms on $H_d(M)$ are equivalent?

**Question 2:** What could go wrong if $D$ is not elliptic?

Possibly relevant references:

- Part B of [this appendix](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bbm%3A978-3-540-74311-8%2F1.pdf) uses covariant derivatives to define $H^d$;
- Lemma 3.2 of [this paper by Delgado and Ruzhansky](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1403.6158.pdf) seems to answer Question 1 using pseudodifferential operators; I wonder if there is different way.

*Added later after reading @Deane's comment:*

**Question 3:** Suppose we define
$$\|f\|_{H^1}=\|\nabla f\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2}.$$
Why this norm stronger than the one defined using an arbitrary first-order operator $D$?

**Question 4:** Here's a simple thing I don't understand. Let's take $M=\mathbb{T}^n$ with the flat metric and $d=2$. We could either define
$$\|f\|_{H^2}=\|f\|_{L^2}+\|\nabla f\|_{L^2}+\|\nabla^2 f\|_{L^2}$$
or
$$\|f\|_{H^2}=\|(1+\Delta)f\|_{L^2}.$$
But for example $\nabla^2$ has mixed partial derivatives and $\Delta$ does not. How does the latter control the former?

Comment: Using the local theory of elliptic operators, it is sufficient to see the Sobolev space in the context of $n$-Torus $\mathbb{T}^n$ and thus proving only in this case that the norms are equivalent.

Comment: Can you refer to some text/notes where they use this definition? It would be helpful

Comment: The operator $D$ should be of first order for this definition to make sense. Else it is certainly not independent of the choice of $D$.

Comment: @MaoWao Thanks, I'll correct this.

Comment: On a Riemannian manifold, the usual way is to use $D = \nabla$. That's clearly a stronger norm than using any other first order operator $D$. To prove that if $D$ is elliptic, then the norm defined using $D$ is equivalent to the one using $\nabla$, it suffices to prove an estimate of the form $$ \|\nabla f\|_2 \le C\|D f\|_2$$ Although there are non-elliptic operators that also satisfy this estimate, their definitions are technical and have little to do with the geometric structure of the manifold. A low tech proof of this estimate using Fourier series can be found in the book by Frank Warner.

Comment: @Deane Thanks. After reading your comment, I realized there were some more things I didn't understand, so I amended the question. Also, looking at Warner, it seems that one could simply define $\|f\|_d$ to be $\|D^d f\|_{L^2}+\|f\|_{L^2}$, instead of the more common $\|D^d f\|_{L^2}+\|D^{d-1}f\|_{L^2}+\cdots+\|f\|_{L^2}$; does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes, that’s right. You can get the other terms using integration by parts. So the two norms are equivalent.

Comment: @Deane Hmm how would I get the term $\|Df\|$ starting from $\|D^2f\|$ and $\|f\|$ using integration by parts?

Comment: For $D = \nabla$, this is straightforward using integration by parts and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. For $D$ elliptic, a similar argument works but you have to use the ellipticity condition.